# Finding element with Erlang list comprehension

Tags: erlang, tuples, list-comprehension, record

I have a list that contains a tuple holding a list and an atom. For example:

```
List = [{[#{aem => "sara",age => "12"},#{aem => "hanna",age => "11"}], blah},
        {[#{aem => "han",age => "12"},#{aem => "anna",age => "21"}], blah1}].
```

I want to fetch the record that matches `aem == "sara"` and include the second element from the tuple (in this case, `blah`) in the result.

Required result: `{[#{aem =>"sara",age=>"12"], blah}`

Comment: [{[X||X<-P,maps:get(aem,X)=="sara"],Dir} || {P,Dir} <-List],

Answer (score 2):

```
1> List = [{[#{aem => "sara",age => "12"},#{aem => "hanna",age => "11"}], blah},
1>         {[#{aem => "han",age => "12"},#{aem => "anna",age => "21"}], blah1}].
[{[#{aem => "sara",age => "12"},
   #{aem => "hanna",age => "11"}],
  blah},
 {[#{aem => "han",age => "12"},#{aem => "anna",age => "21"}],
  blah1}]
2> [ {L, Y} || {X, Y} <- List, L <- [[M || M<-X, maps:get(aem, M) =:= "sara"]], L =/= []].
[{[#{aem => "sara",age => "12"}],blah}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your second list comprehension like below:

```
-module(foo).
-compile(export_all).
start()->
    List = [{[#{aem => "sara",age => "12"},
              #{aem => "hanna",age => "11"}], "blah"},
            {[#{aem => "han",age => "12"},
              #{aem => "anna",age => "21"}], "blah1"}],
    listcomp(List).
listcomp([]) -> [];
listcomp([{P, Dir} | T]) ->
    case [X || X <- P, maps:get(aem, X) == "sara" ] of
        [] -> listcomp(T);
        Res -> [{Res, Dir} | listcomp(T)]
    end.
```

Comment: Calculating `listcomp` twice?

Comment: Now I bring this calculation into a function. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that `aem`s are somewhat unique (at least within each group of *people*):

```
 [{[Person], Atom} || {People, Atom} <- List, Person = #{aem := "sara"} <- People].
```

That would produce the following result:

```
[{[#{aem => "sara",age => "12"}],blah}]
```

But, in order to match your expected result precisely, you need to pick just one element from that list. You can use `hd/1` for that (if you know that you’ll **always** have at least one element or you don’t mind crashing if you don’t:

```
 1> hd([{[Person], Atom} || {People, Atom} <- List, Person = #{aem := "sara"} <- People].
 {[#{aem => "sara",age => "12"}],blah}
```